Some question about go encoding/json read more bytes
In go encoding/json src code, If there is not enough data in decoder.buf when decoding, it will read some data from the reader it holds, this is source coude
func (dec *Decoder) refill() error {
    // Make room to read more into the buffer.
    // First slide down data already consumed.
    if dec.scanp > 0 {
        dec.scanned += int64(dec.scanp)
        n := copy(dec.buf, dec.buf[dec.scanp:])
        dec.buf = dec.buf[:n]
        dec.scanp = 0
    }

    // Grow buffer if not large enough.
    const minRead = 512
    if cap(dec.buf)-len(dec.buf) < minRead {
        newBuf := make([]byte, len(dec.buf), 2*cap(dec.buf)+minRead)
        copy(newBuf, dec.buf)
        dec.buf = newBuf
    }

    // Read. Delay error for next iteration (after scan).
    n, err := dec.r.Read(dec.buf[len(dec.buf):cap(dec.buf)])
    dec.buf = dec.buf[0 : len(dec.buf)+n]

    return err
}

src link:https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/encoding/json/stream.go#L146
question:
I I wonder if there has such a problem: it seems to read at least 512 bytes each time，if the reader is a tcpConn, and the decoder read more bytes than decode need(like decoder just need 100 bytes to decode a struct), so if others need the tcp bytes, it will block, because the bytes have been read by decoder.
I have a struct which have header and body two fields, the header is encoded by json and the body is encoded by gob, my decode code is like this
func decode(conn net.Conn) {
    h := &header{}
    if err := json.NewDecoder(conn).Decode(h); err != nil {
        log.Printf("rpc server: decode header error: %v", err)
    }

        b := &body{}
        if err := gob.NewDecoder(conn).Decode(req); err != nil {
                log.Printf("rpc server: decode body error: %v", err)
        }
}

My code sometimes can work sometimes can't, because the json encoder some time will read more bytes than head struct size.
In the one case, the tcp connection have both head and body bytes, the json decoder will read both part(because the decoder try to read at least 512 bytes each time as above said),so the gob decoder will block because no bytes to decode. In this case, my application can't work,
In the other case: There are not enough bytes in the connection when json decoder reading from the connection(just have headers encode byte), this code can work

It's usually not a good idea to share the same stream between multiple buffered readers. json.Decoder has an escape hatch, but as you see it's easy to miss and not all steam consumers will have that. When dealing with a custom protocol like this, you would normally use a single bufio.Reader and parse out the individual sections of the protocol yourself.

@JimB I have a question：Is it reasonable to design json.decoder like this? I think if you call json.Decoder.Docode(struct A), it should just read size(A) form reader, and shouldn't buffered more bytes, or maybe there should have a config func to control the buffered behavior

@JimB the escape hatch is meaning json.Decoder.Buffered()?

Yes, I mean json.Decoder allows you to extract buffered data. No it's not reasonable to design a streaming decoder like that, because you don't know how long the data to be decoded is, so you would need to read by single bytes which is extremely inefficient. That effect though is exactly what I just recommended, create a bufio.Reader of your own, extract the json header then unmarshal it in isolation.

make sense, thanks for your answer

Use Decoder.Buffered to get a reader for the buffered bytes. Combine with io.MultiReader to make a reader for all remaining bytes of the connection:
func decode(conn net.Conn) {
    h := &header{}
    dec := json.NewDecoder(conn)
    if err := dec.Decode(h); err != nil {
        log.Printf("rpc server: decode header error: %v", err)
    }

    r := io.MultiReader(dec.Buffered(), conn)

    b := &body{}
    if err := gob.NewDecoder(r).Decode(b); err != nil {
        log.Printf("rpc server: decode body error: %v", err)
    }
}


if there have a such a way, which not allowed json.Decoder buffered more bytes, just Read only what is needed to decode。
